# Python Appending lists

Tags: python, list, random, append

I need to add a randomly selected movie to a list:

```
def rand():
    displayList = []
    item = print(random.choice(movies_list))
    displayList.append(item)
    print(displayList)
```

But this doesn't seem to add "item" to "displayList"
Help??

Comment: remove the first print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print statement is meant for Standard output. `print` evaluates each expression in turn and writes the resulting object to standard output. So remove the print statement in assignment. You can use a `global` variable to store the values and you can use `global` keyword to access it inside the function.

```
displayList = []
def rand():
    global displayList
    item = random.choice(movies_list)
    displayList.append(item)
    print(displayList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting `item = print(random.choice(movies_list))`? This assigns the return value of `print()` to `item`, not the result of `random.choice(movies_list)` to `item.

Instead, assign the randomly chosen movie to `item`, then print `item`.

```
def rand():
    displayList = []
    item = random.choice(movies_list)
    print(item) #now you print what movie you picked
    displayList.append(item)
    print(displayList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here 'displayList' is a local variable, so it will reset to empty each time you call the rand. Move it out the scope of the function and call the function with 'displayList' as parameter will solve your problem. Also don't let the return value of the print take the position of item.

```
displayList = []
def rand(displayList):
    item = random.choice(movies_list)
    displayList.append(item)
    print(displayList)
```